# How to truncate value after decimal point

Tags: c, truncate

A user enters a double value like this: 2423242.6789. What can I do to only scan 2423242?

Comment: why not just read the float then cast to int?

Comment: I've tried (int) x and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to work" mean? What did you do, what did you *expect* the result to be and how did the cast fail to meet those expectations?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a positive number, use `floor()`

```
#include <math.h> 

double x;
scanf("%lf", &x);
x = floor(x);
// or 
x = x < 0.0 ? ceil(x) : floor(x); // to cope with + and - doubles
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still doesn't work

Comment: @Cailou post your 1) code 2) input 3) output seen and 4) desired output.

Comment: double jdn; 
      printf("enter a JDN greater than 2299160: ";
      scanf("%f", &jdn);
lc = jdn + 68569;
   nc = ((4 * lc) / 146097);
   lc = lc - ((146097 * nc + 3) / 4);
   ic = ((4000 * (lc + 1)) / 1461001);
   lc = lc - ((1461 * ic) / 4) + 31;
   jc = ((80 * lc) / 2447);
   day = lc - ((2447 * jc) / 80);
   lc = (jc / 11);
As you can see, only the value before decimal point is needed for calculation.

Comment: @Cailou ,Use `%lf` for scanning a `double` or else declare `jdn` as a `float`.

Comment: @Cailou  1) Use `scanf("%lf", &jdn);`  (add the l) 2) What types are `lc, nc,jc,day`?  3) What was the input?

Comment: @chux: long lc, nc, jc; int day; Input:  2423242.6789. I've added l to scanf and it works :D

Comment: @chux: I do something like (long) jdn...it produces 2423242

Comment: @Cailou Julian Day calculation?  Method will have trouble with negative numbers.  But then the prompt did say "greater than 2299160".  Good luck

Comment: @chux: yeah...:D I'm new to C so that's why

Comment: @chux: just tested your code above one more time and it worked perfectly. Thanks again for your help...Now i found 2 different ways to get the same result :D

Comment: @Cailou "it doesn't work" is **MEANINGLESS**. You need to explain *WHY* it doesn't work if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an integer specifier, e.g.

```
unsigned long long x;
if ( 1 != scanf( "%llu", &x ) )
      // error handling...
```

however this causes undefined behaviour if the input didn't fit into `x`.

A more reliable way would be to read characters into a buffer (e.g. via `fgets`) and then use `strtoul` to convert to integer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've not seen those things before. Will definitely study them.